# Error in Installing linear algebra library (lla) for Common Lisp (CLISP) - Emacs SLIME, Quicklisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, algebra, quicklisp

- The Common Lisp Cookbook - https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/arrays.html
- Linear Algebra library (lla) - https://github.com/tpapp/lla

I tried to install Linear Algebra libary (lla) using quicklisp in Emacs' SLIME repl, but it didn't work. The error message is:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :lla)
...
Unable to load foreign library (LIBBLAS.DLL-68919).
  FFI:OPEN-FOREIGN-LIBRARY: Cannot open library "libblas.dll"
   [Condition of type CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR]
```

I'm using ANSI Common Lisp (CLISP) in Emacs 27.1 SLIME-mode (Windows 64 bits operating system). How can I install "lla" library properly?

Comment: I removed tag `emacs` because this doesn't sound like an Emacs question. It looks like the library you're trying to use is a Common Lisp library, not an Emacs-Lisp library. If that's incorrect then feel free to add the tag back.

Comment: The error message is complaining that it can't find libblas. Have you installed BLAS/LAPACK? I don't know how to do that on Windows, but if you can figure it out I imagine you'll be able to load lla.

Comment: You can install something like OpenBlas https://www.openblas.net/ on windows.I recall having issues with the CFFI bindings and having to mess around with them to get it to work. One reason why I stay in Linux for this sort of software